# Cannot initialize SpringServlet for Jersey : JacksonJaxbJsonProvider must be a singleton

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jersey

I am a REST/Jersey newbie and I have a simple RESTful Java web service implemented with the Spring version of Jersey...

```
@Service
@Path("/getAccountBalance")
public class GetAccountBalanceService {

@Autowired
private ILicenseService licenseService;

  @GET
  @Path("/{param}")
  public Response provideService(@PathParam("param") String licenseUUID) {

    License license = this.licenseService.getByUUID(licenseUUID);

    String output = "Balance on the account : " + license.getBalanceValue();

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

  }
```

and have configured jersey servlet with Spring support in web.xml..

```
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
             com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.freedomoss.crowdcontrol.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I try to call the service I get the following exception....

```
Dec 19, 2014 11:34:04 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
 INFO: Registering Spring bean, jsonProvider, of type com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider as a provider class

  SEVERE: Exception occurred when intialization
 java.lang.RuntimeException: The scope of the component class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider must be a singleton
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory.wrap(IoCProviderFactory.java:102)
```

So I am using JacksonJaxbJsonProvider in another part of my application, so why is Jersey spring touching this class and then complaining about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this error go away by searching through the application context XML (which was huge for my app) for all references to JacksonJaxbJsonProvider. I saw that 2 separate beans were defined as using this class. I removed one of them and added the singleton attribute to the one I kept...

```
<bean id="jaxbObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" scope="singleton">
    <property name="mapper" ref="jaxbObjectMapper" />
</bean>
```

Hope this helps someone.